# delay not reinitialised correctly in jquery animation queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with the animation queue of my message box...

I've made a function to notify the user about errors or informations from the application.
The message is displayed during 5 seconds (delay), but the user has the possibility to hide it by clicking the cross button in the msgbox.

**What I wanted :** calling notify() will slideDown my msgbox and auto fadeOut() it after 5 seconds. Recalling notify() before the 5 seconds delay will hide() the current msgbox and slide Down a new msgbox which will again auto fadeOut() after 5 seconds.

**What really appends with my code :** If I recall my "notify()" function before the end of the delay, the msgbox will be hided correctly, but the delay of the fresh displayed msgbox will be shorter than my 5 seconds...

I tried with the jQuery function ".stop(true,true)" to reset the delay but it doesn't work. Has anyone an idea how to solve my problem ?

Here is a fiddle of my snippet : http://jsfiddle.net/wvqkT/
. To see the problem, click the button, wait 2 seconds then re click the button. Do it 5 times and you'll see that the msgbox will disappear too soon...

Here is the code of my function

```
function notify(type, message) {
$('#notificationMessage').stop(true, true).hide();
var classes = 'info warning success error';
$('#notificationMessage').removeClass(classes);
var types = classes.split(' ');
var title = "";

if (type === types[0]) {
    title = "Information";
} else if (type === types[1]) {
    title = "Attention";
} else if (type === types[2]) {
    title = "Succès";
} else if (type === types[3]) {
    title = "Erreur";
} else {
    title = "Information";
    type = types[0];
}
$('#notificationMessage').addClass(type);
$('#notificationMessage h3').empty().append(title);
$('#notificationMessage p').empty().append(message);
$('#notificationMessage').slideDown({ queue: false }).delay(5000).fadeOut(3000); }

$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    notify($('#type').val(),"This is the message to show....");
});
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot cancel `Delay()` you should use setTimeout() instead.

```
var timeout;
function notify(type, message) { 
    //..your old code here
    $('#notificationMessage').slideDown(function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout); 
        timeout = setTimeout(function() { $(this).fadeOut(3000) }, 5000);
    }) 
}
```

### jsFiddle

From the jQuery page:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

Answer (score 1):

As for jquery 1.9, you can now use `finish()` method which will clear timeout used by delay method { hooks.stop.call( this, true ); }

NOTE: in your sample code, you need then to push slideDown() method in queue, not explicitly using `queue: false`

```
$('#notificationMessage').finish().hide();
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ySGWx/)